# Does an atom have more higher energy energy levels than lower energy levels?

Tags: electrons, thermal-radiation

I read online that a photon has more higher energy state energy levels to go to than lower energy. Is this correct? What concept is this?

Comment: This basically amounts to asking, “are there more positive integers above 10 than below?”

Comment: @leftaroundabout teacher wanted me to get a reference

Comment: Where did you read this online?

Comment: @Thomas a friend told me this while explaining the shape of the spectral curve

Comment: Are you referring to the Planck-curve spectrum?

Comment: which coordinate in the atom?, there are two, and for a question like this, both are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The atomic spectrum is *bound from below*. If the spectrum consisted only of discrete levels, like that of a harmonic oscillator, then for sny arbitrarily chosen level we would have a finite number of levels with energies below it, and an infinite number of levels of higher energy. The atoms however have spectrum that is partly discrete and partly continuous - once we are in the continuous spectrum, counting levels become meaningless.

**Remark:**  To clarify things a bit: an atomic spectrum consists of a discrete part, containing an infinite number of energy levels bounded from below and from above (they are typically taken to have negative energies), and a continuous part (with positive energies). The continuous part of the spectrum presents the unbound states, and one could argue that we cannot really call it *an atom* (or we may agree to call it an *ionized atom*), but these states must be considered when dealing with the absorption and the emission - e.g., an electron fom continuum may emit a photon, landing in on of the atomic orbitals. However it is also possible that an electron changes from one continuum state to another - the process whose cross-section will be different from scattering in vacuum (aka *Compton scattering) due to the presence of the atom. States in continuum cannot be counted, but one still could argue that the continuum for absorption is *bigger* than the continuum for emission.

I do not provide here more details about the discrete spectrum, since these have been treated in the answer by @AndrewSteane

Comment: Nice answer. "The atoms however have spectrum that is partly discrete and partly continuous" Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei I added some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

For example, the energy levels for bound states of hydrogen are at $E = -E_R/n^2$ where $E_R$ is about $13.6$ eV and $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to $1$. So the ground state is at $n=1$, the first excited state is at $n=2$ and so on. If the electron starts in a state of some given $n$ above 1, then there are only a finite number of states of lower energy (smaller $n$) but an infinite number of states of higher energy (higher $n$).

For other atoms the situation is similar except now the energy depends on more variables and there is no simple formula in general. A formula which works quite well for group 1 elements is
$$
E = - \frac{E_R}{(n - \delta_l)^2}
$$
where $n$ is an integer from 1 to infinity and $\delta_l$ is a real number
which depends on another integer quantum number called $l$ which takes values between zero and $n-1$. In this case $\delta_l$ is of order $1$ for small $l$ and tends to zero for high $l$. So you see again, there are plenty of states with energy above any particular one you might pick. An infinite number of them! But the higher ones are packed very close together in energy and atoms in those states would not be very stable; they would either decay to a lower state or, often more likely, lose an electron altogether through a collision with something else.